# inserting an array into sql server and mysql database using c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql-server, arrays

I have a List in C# for my Winforms application:

```
List<string> StudentSubjects = new List<>(string);
```

I have inserted these into List :

```
 StudentSubjects.Add("Physics", "Chemistry", "Mathematics", "English");
```

Now i have a table: **STUDENTS**

```
----------
**StudentID     | SubjectsSelected**
---------
STDNT001        |  [HERE all subjects selected by the student should be inserted]     
STDNT002        |  Physics, Chemistry, Mathematics, English
STDNT002        |  Physics, Chemistry, Mathematics, English
----------
```

Shall i use the implode function for MySql? But what's the syntax? Also , what to do for SQL Server.

I am doing:

```
string query =
"INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES 
('S001', implode('" + StudentSubjects.ToArray() + " ')) "
```

But there's some error. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your query

```
string query = @"
    INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES 
    ('S001', '" + string.Join(",", StudentSubjects) + "')";
```

However, you better use parametrized query, instead of string concatenation.

For MySQL:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = @"
        INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES 
        ('S001', ?subjects)";
    var param = command.Parameters.Add("?subjects", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
    param.Value = string.Join(",", StudentSubjects);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

For SQL Server:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = @"
        INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES 
        ('S001', @subjects)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("subjects", string.Join(",", StudentSubjects))
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @Alex Aza : sir, can you please help me with the parameterized query code also.

Comment: @Alex Aza : sir,is this valid for both : Mysql as well as SQL Server?

Comment: thanks a lot sir, also, if i use Implode function , then will it work? I have a Linux server , so have PHP.

Comment: @Alex Aza : also, how would i read only particular subjects name from the table? like if i only want to view students who have opted for English, then what would be the query? -- select * from students where SubjectsSelected = 'English', then will it work?

Comment: @Alex Aza : or it would be this : select * from students where SubjectsSelected LIKE %English%

Comment: @sqlchild - you can use LIKE '%Subject%'. However, it is better to have 3 tables: `Students`, `Subjects`, `StudentSubjects`. This way you would not need to parse a string.